# Error received when updating the SDK with the SDK Manager

Tags: android

I'm completely frustrated with the Android SDK Manager.

I'm running Win 7 Home edition and have the SDK installed in its own top level directory on my D:\ drive.

When I run SDK Setup.exe from the command line (and I've even opened the prompt as an administrator), I get an error when trying to update the packages.

The SDK manager is telling me that I need to install the SDK Tools rev 7.  But when I accept the license, I get an error message stating:

"A folder failed to be renamed or removed" yada yada yada.  The Installing Archives window says "Failed to rename directory D:\android-sdk-windows\tools to D:\android-sdk-windows\temp\ToolPackage.old01."

I looked here for help:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/4b784f3eb1e096fd/ecadfb28ce5daf5f?lnk=gst&q=cannot+rename+folder#ecadfb28ce5daf5f

but the content there didn't help.

1. I DO have my antivirus (AVG) disabled.
2. I DO NOT have any other programs running -- just the command prompt to launch the SDK Manager.
3. I have even given the everyone group, for the D:\android-sdk-windows\ folder, full control.
4. I tried to rename the tools directory before starting the SDK Manager but then I get an error that a batch file cannot be found when I try to launch SDK Setup.exe.  Grrrr.

None of this works.

Suggestions how to get the package to update without error are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

A simple thing,

There will be zipped file after this error has been occured. Meaning that Updated tools got store as 
**tools_r16-windows.zip** in C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\temp

Just extract it and copy it in our tools folder
**C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools**

Enjoy:)
I think ths might help. Please give your comments!!

Comment: Yep, that's what I did :) Additionally, ADT discovered the old package that I backed up in tools-old and I could uninstall it

Answer (score 4):

If you get this error while using Eclipse on a 64-bit Window 7 (might 32-bit as well), exit Eclipse, go to your SDK folder and run "SDK Manager.exe" as Administrator. In my case, Eclipse turned out to be what locked the folder in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

@ Stratos - Thank you for your instructions, they worked for me.

1. Go to Android\
         android-sdk\
           tools\
2. Delete "source.properties" (Right click - delete)
3. Open SDK Manager and update

And everyone lived happily ever after...

Comment: Nope, doesn't help on my system.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use 64 bit java or 64 bit eclipse. That's almost certainly your problem.

Comment: Yep.  I'm on a 64 bit system.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  My apologies if I should have known that otherwise... but it wasn't listed here:  http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html

Comment: In fact, that requirements page states it is possible to use a 64 bit system.  So I'm a little confused right now.

Comment: You can be on windows 64, that's fine. Just install the 32 bit version of java and eclipse. It's not well documented at all, I've just experienced this and seen it many times.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. For me it was a bit circular, the SDK manager had a hold at source.properties and closing the process terminated the update. I deleted android-sdk\tools\source.properties before running the SDK manager and it all worked. Oh and I was not updating through Eclipse so it is not an Eclipse problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't vote yet, or I would have voted for Stratos.

I had already disabled my Norton antivirus (after reading other posts).
Removing the source.properties file helped.

Don't forget to run SDK manager with admin rights if not already.

Answer (score 0):

There is another simple way:

When the SDK asks to install the Java SE JDK press back and then press next. This time it will detect the installed JDK. I solved this problem twice with this method

Answer (score 0):

Use [Unlocker](http://download.cnet.com/Unlocker/3000-2248_4-10493998.html) to unlock the tools folder.

Right click on tools folder -> Unlocker. This way you don't even have to find out what is locking the folder...

Comment: What process needs to be unlocked? If I unlock all, the updater itself stalls.

Comment: In my case unlocking all did the trick. Sadly I cant try it out again, because after successfully updating the SDK I dont have the problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Start task manage and end Adb.exe. Thisnisnthe program that has a hold on the folder. Rename the tools folder to some other name eg. 'toolsold'. Then extract the zip file containing the new tools folder. Rerun the updates and it should be detected as updated and it should proceed with the outstanding tasks.

Comment: Delete toolsold backup folder after completion.

Answer (score 0):

Run SDK manager as Administrator, this fixed for me